# Error compiling php5.5.18 on MacOSX 10.10 (yosemite)

Tags: php, c++, macos, apache

I'm trying to compile php (5.5.18, version doesn't matter that much imho) on yosemite but it fails during the link phase. It looks like some apache symbols are gone?

(The following worked perfectly on Mountain Lion, but fails on Yosemite.)

```
cc -bundle -bundle_loader /usr/sbin/httpd -L/usr/lib -laprutil-1 -lldap -llber -lexpat -liconv -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -L/usr/lib -lapr-1 -lpthread -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load
<SNIP>
sapi/apache2handler/php_functions.o main/internal_functions.o  -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lexslt -ltidy -lresolv -ledit -lncurses -lltdl -lldap -llber -lstdc++ -liconv -liconv -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lbz2 -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lxml2 -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -lbz2 -lxml2 -lnetsnmp -lcrypto -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxslt  -o libs/libphp5.bundle && cp libs/libphp5.bundle libs/libphp5.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ap_get_server_version", referenced from:
      _zif_apache_get_version in php_functions.o
      _zm_info_apache in php_functions.o
  "_ap_log_error", referenced from:
      _php_pre_config in sapi_apache2.o
      _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
      _php_apache_sapi_log_message in sapi_apache2.o
  "_ap_log_rerror", referenced from:
      _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
      _php_apache_sapi_log_message in sapi_apache2.o
  "_unixd_config", referenced from:
      _zm_info_apache in php_functions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

Any ideas? I checked /usr/lib/libapr-1.dylib (with nm -g) and the symbols are not present. Where should I normally find those symbols? Is this missing a lib? What's really weird is that my custom build script worked fine on 10.9 but fails on 10.10

Thanks for the help!
Nicolas

Comment: This may not be a direct answer to your issue, but have considered using macports or home brew to install php?  Also, I thought OSx came with apache & PHP by default?

Comment: @MatthewBrown Homebrew is currently broken on Yosemite.

Comment: @Qix homebrew works fine on yosemite! what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @BradAllred [Please research first.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=homebrew%20broken%20on%20yosemite) There have been many reports and many affected.

Comment: @Qix I have it running just fine on Yosemite; no research needed to establish that fact. The problems referred to in your link suggest some *packages* (who wants to use gcc anyway :p ) from homebrew have problems under Yosemite. It doesnt follow that homebrew itself has these problems (it doesnt). wether or not the PHP package works or not i do not know.

Comment: `who wants to use gcc anyway` Are you kidding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that it was using the following include path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/apache2/
```

Instead of the normal one:

```
/usr/include/apache2/
```

Some more info:

```
$ xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx

MacOSX10.9.sdk - OS X 10.9 (macosx10.9)
SDKVersion: 10.9
Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
PlatformVersion: 1.1
PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
ProductBuildVersion: 13F26
ProductCopyright: 1983-2014 Apple Inc.
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductUserVisibleVersion: 10.9.5
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
```

Strange, I hope it helps other people.

Best,
Nicolas

Comment: If you install Xcode 6.1, you'll get the `10.10` version of that directory created: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/apache2`. FYI: Mavericks ships with Apache 2.2 and Yosemite ships with Apache 2.4. There are some differences in the libs.

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcode 6.1 at first, then:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
```

Answer (score 0):

I used MacPorts to install some libraries (like mcrypt), and then I compiled the 5.5.18 source code (with Xcode command line) using the following ./configure -command:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --sysconfdir=/private/etc --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-icu-dir=/usr --with-ldap=/usr --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-libedit=/usr --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --without-pear --with-pear=no --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock --with-readline=/usr --enable-shmop --with-snmp=/usr --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --with-tidy --enable-wddx --with-xmlrpc --with-iconv-dir=/usr --with-xsl=/usr --enable-zip --with-mcrypt=/opt/local/include --without-iconv --with-freetype-dir=/opt/local --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-openssl=/usr --with-curl=/usr --with-zlib=/usr --with-bz2=/usr